# What is the alternative for Canvas to have text editing in the application

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, html5-canvas

I want to develop a sketchpad using JavaScript, HTML and CSS, which involves free hand drawing and typing notes.

I tried developing with HTML Canvas but after a long time i couldnt develop the text editing features like saving the text content and re-edit the saved file in Canvas. And also i was told its not recommended to use the canvas for text editing feature.

Suggest me a Good alternative for canvas which would support text editing and free drawing function for mobile environment. Am trying to build the application in phonegap for android and IOS platform.

Answer (score 1):

There really are only two viable solutions for trying to do what you're doing and that is

1. Canvas
2. Dom

#### Canvas

Rendering text in canvas can be pretty slow on mobile devices. However, to add your saving feature it should just be a case of saving the text, its position, and any effects you've applied to localstorage. On load, retrieve the information and re-draw it.

#### DOM

Actually creating the effects with DOM will be significantly easier as you can simply use CSS. But to save, you're still going to have to use Javascript (like the canvas method) and store your text properties.

You'll probably also struggle to include some of your other features if you go for a pure canvas approach.

---

*Other alternatives*

#### Canvas & DOM

You could do a combination of both as each has it's advnatages - but can complicate things somewhat.

#### Flash

This will rule out iOS but Android should be sweet.

#### Native

This will require your app to be written twice (objective-c for ios and java for android). But you'll get the best performance and features.

Answer (score 0):

you can try DOM Sprites..its good..check demo.    http://buildnewgames.com/assets/article//dom-sprites/dom-sprite-demo.html